# How to integrate PHP with javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < massages.length; i++) 
{
    commentBoxDiv.appendChild(createCommentBox("<?php echo $massages[i]['likes']; ?> people like this.", i));
}
```

but I don't know how to break the syntax in order to access the `i` variable.

Comment: Asking someone for a massage or message will certainly elicit different responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) and some creativity, you can work out a solution like the following:

```
<script>
    var messages = <?php echo json_encode($messages); ?>;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        commentBoxDiv.appendChild(createCommentBox(messages[i].likes + " %d people like this.", i));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JS variables inside php code block. You must iterate `$massages` array and make from them JS objects.